# VB6 GMTOffset to C#

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

I am trying to convert the code below from VB6 to C#. I am just not sure where to begin, I guess maybe because I am sucked way to much into VB6 and can't seem to take a step back.

```vb
Private Function GMT_OFFSET() As Integer
    '****DECLARE VARIABLES
    Dim dtNow As Date, dtEngland As Date
    Dim dtGMT As SYSTEMTIME
    '****GET SYSTEM TIME INFORMATION
    Call GetSystemTime(dtGMT)
    dtNow = Now
    dtEngland = dtGMT.wYear & "-" & dtGMT.wMonth & "-" & dtGMT.wDay & " " & dtGMT.wHour & ":" & dtGMT.wMinute & ":" & dtGMT.wSecond
    '****RETURN QUARTER HOURS
    GMT_OFFSET = DateDiff("n", dtEngland, dtNow) \ 15
End Function
```

I know GetSystemTime is a Win32 API, obviously don't want to do PInvoke in .NET but rather use the pure objects in the .NET Framework.

Comment: How about you tell us what you're trying to achieve, rather than what your VB code would have been...

Comment: Thanks Jon. Well thats the thing im also figuring out at the same time. Basically in the end, it is grabbing the result from a value from a property and adds a TimeZone offset from GMT quarter hours (-20) and substracts the LOCAL_GMTOFFSET which is in the VB6 code as above. It is just the above code I need translation of, that's all. in the end - I just need to know how to get the Local GMTOffset. in quarterly hours

Comment: I'd be extremely nervous of trying to port a method whose purpose you don't even know. How would you know whether you'd got it right or not? Chances are you should be changing how you approach the problem in the first place - where is this being *used*? There may well be a better solution to the bigger picture.

Comment: it is being used in the processing engine of the VB6 code. That is quite lengthy to get into (literally). All I know is that it IS being used and it IS required. Because I only have half of the things, I can't quite wait until I get the remaining of the stuff to put through the whole process. So to be proactive I need to at least try to put this in code and alter it/tweak it once I get all the details. Don't want to be sitting twiddling my thumbs :)

Comment: I think your time would be best spent trying to work out exactly what the bigger picture is, to be honest.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Well, I did explain earlier what it needs to do. It needs to get the quarterly hours from the GMT Offset.

Comment: My point is that that's not the bigger picture. Chances are once you understand *why* you're doing this, it will prompt you to make wider changes. But it seems you disagree, and of course I can't tell you what to do.

Comment: Thanks Jon. No, not at all. I don't disagree :-) And I guarentee that this is the only place it is being used in code. This IS the extent of the "bigger picture".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near direct translation:

```
//Private Function GMT_OFFSET() As Integer
int GMT_OFFSET()
{
  //'****DECLARE VARIABLES
  //Dim dtNow As Date, dtEngland As Date
  DateTime dtNow, dtEngland;
  //Dim dtGMT As SYSTEMTIME
  //'****GET SYSTEM TIME INFORMATION
  //Call GetSystemTime(dtGMT)
  //dtNow = Now
  //dtEngland = dtGMT.wYear & "-" & dtGMT.wMonth & "-" & dtGMT.wDay & " " & dtGMT.wHour & ":" & dtGMT.wMinute & ":" & dtGMT.wSecond
  dtEngland = DateTime.UtcNow;
  dtNow = dtEngland.ToLocalTime;
  //'****RETURN QUARTER HOURS
  //GMT_OFFSET = DateDiff("n", dtEngland, dtNow) \ 15
  return Convert.ToInt32((dtNow - dtEngland).TotalMinutes) / 15;
//End Function
}
```

NB VB6's `DateDiff(interval,date1,date2)` results in intervals based upon `date2 - date1`, *not* vice versa.

But the one-liner is:

```
return Convert.ToInt32(TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMinutes) / 15;
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, you are looking for something along the lines of:

```
        var dtNow = DateTime.Now;
        var dtOffset = (dtNow.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(dtNow)).TotalMinutes / 15;
```

You may need to adjust the offset negatively if the universal time is greater than the current system time.

Answer (score 1):

The system time:

```
DateTime systemDateTime = DateTime.Now;
```

But more importantly, the offset the system is running with:

```
TimeZoneInfo systemTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
TimeSpan offset = systemTimeZone.GetUtcOffset();
Int32 offsetMinutes = offset.Hours * 60 + offset.Minutes;
```